# Timepicker icon is not displaying in Timepicker component using mui react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I just copied/imported the Timepicker component from Mui react , the timepicker icon is not displaying and also getting error on renderInput. Any help would be appreciable.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Dayjs } from 'dayjs';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { TimePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker';

export default function BasicTimePicker() {
const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Dayjs | null>(null);
return (
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
  <TimePicker
    label="Basic example"
    value={value}
    onChange={(newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue);
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
 );
}
```

Comment: Please add the error to your question.

Comment: @RubenSmn Added error screenshot, but seems thr error is no where related to icon

Answer (score 0):

There is no `renderInput` on the `TimePicker` element according to the [MUI x TimePicker docs](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/time-picker/#props).

You could use the `slots` prop to use custom components. Something like

```js
<TimePicker
  label="Basic example"
  value={value}
  onChange={(newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  }}
  slots={{
    TextField: CustomText,
  }}
/>
```